# The congruence of two partitioned matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Two $(m+n)\times (m+n)$ real symmetric matrices $X$ and $Y$ can be partitioned as follows:

$X=\left( \begin{matrix} A_{n\times n} & O_{n\times m} \\ O_{m\times n} & C_{m\times m} \end{matrix} \right)$
and
$Y=\left( \begin{matrix} B_{n\times n} & O_{n\times m} \\ O_{m\times n} & D_{m\times m} \end{matrix} \right)$.

I am wondering whether $C$ is congruent to $D$ if we know $X$ is congruent to $Y$, and $A$ is congruent to $B$. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean congruent in the [sense defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, and it can be seen as a straight-forward consequence of [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

---

A direct proof might look like this: let $P,Q$ be such that $P^TXP = Y$ and $Q^TAQ = B$.  It follows that
$$
\left[P \pmatrix{Q^{-1} & 0\\0 & I}\right]^T \pmatrix{A&0\\0&C} \left[P \pmatrix{Q^{-1} & 0\\0 & I}\right] = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&D}
$$
That is, $\operatorname{diag}(A,C)$ is congruent to $\operatorname{diag}(A,D)$. From here, we would need to deduce that $C$ is congruent to $D$.